# Does Soulknife Rogue's feature Psychic Whispers work on enemies?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue

In Tasha’s Cauldron Of Everything, Soulknife Rogue gets the following feature at 3rd level:

Psychic Whispers. You can establish telepathic communication between yourself and others—perfect for quiet infiltration. As an action, choose one or more creatures you can see, up to a number of creatures equal to your proficiency bonus, and then roll one Psionic Energy die. For a number of hours equal to the number rolled, the chosen creatures can speak telepathically with you, and you can speak telepathically with them. To send or receive a message (no action required), you and the other creature must be within 1 mile of each other. A creature can’t use this telepathy if it can’t speak any languages, and a creature can end the telepathic connection at any time (no action required). You and the creature don’t need to speak a common language to understand each other.

---

Can this be applied to enemies? If yes, can enemies stop this telepathic connection?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes to both.**

The description says "creatures" so as long as they can speak a language you can designate them as a target for that Psychic Whispers. Nothing says the creature must be willing.

For stopping the telepathy, it similarly says "a creature". Again, having no specification of enemies, allies, or willingness, so they would be able to stop this as well.